# I'm loosing values in parameter service when I refresh pages in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

I'm using msal angular  library to log users in my app.

Once the user has logged I save the value in my parameter service to share it with the rest of the components.

parameter.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ParameterService {
....
empleado:Empleado;
}
```

home.component.ts

```
this.dataService.getEmpleadoByMail(this.usuario.username)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.parameterService.empleado = data;            
        this.router.navigate(['/planificador', data.empId, 'proyectos']);
      }
      , err => console.error(err)
      , () => { }
    );
```

Once the employee associated with the login has been obtained, the projects that can be planned are displayed

[image: logeado]

If at this moment I simply refresh this same page I see that the employee property of parameterService is undefined

[image: undefined]

```
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {
....
get empleadoId(): number {
 return this.parameterService.empleadoId;
}
constructor(private parameterService: ParameterService){}
ngOnInit(): void {

if (this.empleado == undefined) {
}
```

I don't know if this is the correct behavior but then it doesn't make sense to use a service injected in your components to share values if you lose them in a refresh right?

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: As Angular is a single page application, refreshing the page would bootstrap the whole application, essentially resetting everything. That is why you store values in cookies, localStorage or design your app in a way that can handle page refreshes correctly.

Comment: Store your login values in local or session storage then generate an interceptor using ```ng g interceptor auth```. Then from there you can set your authentication headers there

Comment: @AldinBradaric When refreshing then I also lose the route and its parameters from which the refresh is made in the browser, right?

Comment: @kintela Not quite. Assuming your route is something like `example.com/subroute?param=test`, refreshing the page would keep the same url. Unless I'm misunderstanding your question.